# How to generate TypeScript definitions for graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a react app based on create react app and TypeScript. I want to replace redux with Apollo graphql client. I define queries in .graphql files and/or gql-Tag using string templates. I want the result/data from apollo’s Query component to be strongly typed, how can I do that? Without writing interfaced and types myself, I want them to be generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good tool for that called [Apollo codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cli), it's part of apollo-cli.

Have a look into their documentation: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cli#apollo-codegengenerate-output

An example to generate the TypeScript definitions would be:

- Download the schema of your server:

`apollo schema:download .schema/graphql.json --endpoint=http://localhost:4000/`

- Generate the types for your queries:

`apollo codegen:generate --schema=.schema/graphql.json --addTypename --target=typescript --queries=src/**/*.{tsx,ts} --outputFlat=src/queries`

Comment: I actually didn't get apollo codegen to work.. Documentation is very outdated, and I ended up debugging apollo codegen, but gave up in the end.. Found another library: graphql-code-generator which worked at last :-) I'm using ApolloClient and that is really great! But couldn't figure out apollo-cli. Actually graphql-code-generator has a template for Apollo too :-)

Comment: Okay, that’s great! I’ll also have a look into that ‘graphql-code-generator’ :)